# capturing the boundary clipped value of an object(THREE.Line)

Tags: three.js

how to get the clipped coordinates across the view port, here the attached image may clearly show what my need is.

[image]

my need is the red color marked coordinates, can any one give your suggestion on the same. THREE.Line, i have used, its a single object(with THREE.LinePieces it constructed)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should specify the space in which you want coordinates: world space, clip space, NDC space, or screen space.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a frustum from your camera projection matrix.

```
var frustum = new THREE.Frustum();
var projectionScreenMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
projectionScreenMatrix.multiplyMatrices( camera.projectionMatrix, camera.matrixWorldInverse );
frustum.setFromMatrix( projectionScreenMatrix );
```

then you have a frustum with 6 planes `frustum.planes`.

You can iterate the planes and find the intersect point with a line using:

```
var plane;
var line = ...your line piece...
var intersect;
var intersects = [];
for( var i = 0; i < frustum.planes.length; i++ ){
    plane = frustum.planes[i];
    intersect = plane.intersectLine( line );
    if( intersect === undefined || intersect.equals(line.start)){
        continue;
    }
    intersects.push( intersect);
}
```

Problem here is that line should be of type `THREE.Line3` so you have to convert your objects of type  `THREE.LinesPieces` to several objects of type `THREE.Line3` and check for all of them individually.

This code is not tested but just a concept to give you an idea of how to handle the problem.